# How to fix: Services: 3011. service already exists Mount path

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-foxx

I have deleted a service using the ArangoDB web interface. When I'm trying to load zipped folder with a new service to the same mount path, I get the error:

> Services: 3011. service already exists Mount path

I'm using arangodb for win64 ver 3.3.13

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,
after much of a hustle, issue solved. The issue may be related to some operations I did before deleting the problematic service:

1. Went to C:\ProgramData\ArangoDB-apps_db\healDB
2. Delete the sub-folder with the relevant service name (it was empty)
3. Enter _appbundles sub-folder
4. Delete the relevant zip file service
5. Restart the DB.

Woila!